# PHP: How do I stop two computers being booked at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I started learning PHP a few weeks ago and I'm quite happy to say that I've made a working computer booking system, I've found developing a project helps me learn best, so that's what I did.

The sign-up/login works perfectly as well as deleting accounts/changing passwords etc., and you can book a computer. However, I don't know how to make it so when a specific computer is booked, say PC-1, that another user cannot come along and book it again, I obviously need some sort of IF statement but I'm not sure how to do it. It needs to be so when the user books PC-1, that computer can no longer be booked and reply with an error telling them to pick a different one. I could implement a queue system but maybe that's a bit too advanced.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if I've done the format wrong I apologise.

I'll post the code below, cheers.

```
<?php

    include 'header.php';
    include 'db.php';
?>

    <?php

        if (isset($_SESSION['studentId'])) {
            echo "<h3>Hello, <h3>".$_SESSION['studentId'];
        //echo "<br><br>It is currently " . date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
        } else {
            echo "You are not logged in";
        }
    ?>

    <form name="book" method="GET" action="booking.php">

    <h4>Select a Computer: </h4>

    <select name="computerId"> <br>

            <?php 

                for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
                {

                    echo "<option name=computerId value=".$i.">PC-".$i."                
</option>";
            }
                echo "<br></br>"
            ?>

    </select>

    <h4>Select a Date: </h4>
    <input type="date" name="arrivalDate">

    <?php

        $arrivalDate = $_GET['arrivalDate'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d')
    //If ($arrivalDate = $date) {

        //  echo "Error, booking date must be in the future!";

    //  } elseif ($arrivalDate < $date) {

    //      echo "Error, booking date cannot be in the past!";

        //}

    ?>

     <h4>Select a Time: </h4>
    <input type="time" name="arrivalTime">

    <h4>What time will you finish?</h4>
    <input type="time" name="departureTime">

    <?php
            $arrivalTime = $_GET['arrivalTime'];
            $departureTime = $_GET['departureTime'];

    if ($arrivalTime = $departureTime) {

        //echo 'Error, you cannot book a computer at the same time you 
 finish with it.';

    } elseif ($arrivalTime > $departureTime) {

        echo 'Error, you cannot book a computer for a time in the past';

    }

    ?>

    <br> <br><input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="alert('Successful 
 Booking!')" value="Book">
   </form>



<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $computerId = $_GET['computerId'];
    $studentId = $_SESSION['studentId'];
    $arrivalDate = $_GET['arrivalDate'];
    $arrivalTime = $_GET['arrivalTime'];
    $departureTime = $_GET['departureTime'];
    $bookingId = $studentId.'-'.$computerId;

    if($_GET['computerId'] = $_SESSION['computerId']) {

    echo 'You cannot book a computer that is already booked!';

}

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Booking (bookingDate, bookingId, studentId, 
   computerId, arrivalDate, arrivalTime, departureTime) values (CURDATE(), 
  '$bookingId', '$studentId', '$computerId', '$arrivalDate', '$arrivalTime', 
  '$departureTime')";

    if ($conn->query($sql)=== TRUE) {
        echo "<br>".$computer."";
    } else {
       // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $sql1 = "SELECT FROM Booking '$computerId', '$arrivalDate', 
   '$arrivalTime', '$departureTime'";

    echo ' <br> You have booked computer '.$computerId.' for 
   '.$arrivalDate.' at '.$arrivalTime.' until '.$departureTime;

    $conn->close();
    }

    //$sql = "SELECT computerId FROM Booking WHERE studentId = 
    '$_SESSION['studentId']"

    //echo "hi";

   ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: With a `UNIQUE` database constraint this can't happen. If you have a table with a booking slot plus computer as a constraint then it's impossible for two people to insert records with the same values. The second person will get an error which you can handle, display as "already booked". Also why is this tagged HTML and CSS? Those seem utterly unrelated to your booking problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i am happy to help you :)
You made a mistake here.

```
if($_GET['computerId'] = $_SESSION['computerId']) {
   echo 'You cannot book a computer that is already booked!';
}
```

What do you think about session. its generate for same computer what you accessed not for server. you just need to verify from database. and return this message.
When some one book then you need to store all information in database. when someone else from other computer make booking verify from database and show this message. because session can't help you.

I hope you get this point.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in the code where youe retrieve the computers joining the computers table to the booking table  with somthing like this:

```
$now = time();//assuming you store time as Unix timestamp
$query = "SELECT * from computers 
WHERE  computers.id NOT IN 
(SELECT c.id from computers c LEFT JOIN 
bookings b ON c.id = b.computerId 
WHERE b.departureTime >  ".$now.")";
```